# Is is possible to include additional non-diverted files in a config-package-dev package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, dpkg

I'm currently struggling with enhancing a package which uses config-package-dev to install a bunch of configurations for PostgreSQL. Those work fine but now I'd also like to include a /etc/sysctl/30-postgresql.conf file which doesn't need to divert anything else. Adding this to my debian/rules has no effect:

```
install::
    dh_install debian/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.d/30-postgresql.conf
```

Do the normal dh_ tools not mix with the concept of a config package? Should I just treat it as another "divert" file and be done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh - I was over thinking the problem. I just needed to edit the debian/package.install file to include the new file:

```
debian/pg_hba.conf.cbnl etc/postgresql/8.4/main
debian/postgresql.conf.cbnl etc/postgresql/8.4/main
debian/30-postgresql.conf /etc/sysctl.d
```

The last file doesn't require any divert magic.